# Remove (Carriage return, Linefeed , New Line character , Space) from clipboard before pasting into a notepad file

Tags: excel, vba, clipboard

I have UDF function to concatenate cells and the function itself works correctly. 
The output of this function is used on a merged cells `”C1:C14”` and sent automatically to clipboard. 
**The problem** is when I paste the contents of clipboard into a notepad file, I found it contains extra empty 14 new line. 
I have used this code after copy and before pasting, but It has no effect at all (without any error raised). 
I already added a reference to (Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library).

```
Sub Trim_Clipboard()

    Dim clipboard As New MSForms.DataObject, str As String
    
    clipboard.GetFromClipboard
    
    If clipboard.GetFormat(1) = False Then MsgBox "clipboard is empty": Exit Sub
     
     str = clipboard.GetText
     
      str = Replace(str, vbCr, "")
       str = Replace(str, vbLf, "")
        str = Replace(str, vbCrLf, "")
         str = Replace(str, vbNewLine, "")
          str = Application.Trim(str)

End Sub
```

And this is the function to concatenate cells:

```
Function ConcRange(rng As Range, Optional Delim As String = ",")
     
    Dim cel As Range
     
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        If Trim(cel) <> "" Then
           ConcRange = CStr(ConcRange) & Delim & CStr(Trim(cel.Value))
        End If
   Next cel
     
   If Len(ConcRange) > 0 Then
     ConcRange = Right(ConcRange, Len(ConcRange) - 1)
   End If
     
End Function
```

**So**, my question is How to remove (Carriage return, Linefeed , New Line character , Space) from clipboard before pasting into a notepad file?

[image]

Comment: Try placing the first replacement to be `str = Replace(str, vbCrLf, "")`, then the one containing `vbNewLine`. Then, placing `str` in Immediate Window, how does it look?

Comment: @FaneDuru , I tried, In immediate window has only extra one empty line, But when I paste on notepad, it is still has extra 14 empty line (the number of merged cells) , I do now know if office clipboard is different from windows clipboard or not.
I think my question needs an API handling.

Comment: Not sure if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74068027/19353309) has anything to do with it, FaneDuru explains that the value of a number of merged cells is kept in the top-left cell of the range. Would only passing the left cell to the clipboard fix the extra empty lines? I had issues myself with empty lines before even when replacing vbCrLf, etc. , I just ended up using re to keep numbers/letters only (avoiding the problem, I know) but you can't do that here I presume.

Comment: Please, edit your question and show us how the cells where from you copy does look. Then, how did you obtain these lines? Wouldn't you press `Alt + Enter`? If yes, the end line separator should be `vbLf` if I remember well. Anyhow, show us the picture, a text as it has been returned and another one **like you want it**.

Comment: @FaneDure , I pasted the output on my final software (Business Object) and it is intelligent enough to remove the extra lines. Anyhow, I added the picture as requested

Comment: What do you mean by "final software (Business Object) "? If your function will insert end lines, etc. they should be comma separated, since your output contains a correct comma separated range, plus a lot of end lines. I would suggest you to read the text file in a variable, then iterate **backwards** between each characters and see what characters are the last (first x digits) using `AscW(mid( str, i, 1)`...

Comment: Your code reads the clipboard into a string, which you then manipulate. What you're not doing is then writing that amended string back to the clipboard.

Comment: @CLR please could you provide an answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60896244/7446760

Comment: @CLR ,yes it is now works correctly 

Comment: I only imagined that you did not update the clipboard, but I thought that you show only part of the code. That's why I asked you to test `str` in Immediate Window. Then, I wanted to know what "final software (Business Object)" is, maybe it is the one adding ending lines...